# Pandas, how to save a complex view in a variable

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to perform some manipulations on a specific part of a pandas dataframe. For that purpose I would like to get a view of my dataframe, save that in a variable and work with the variable (so as to not have to recompute the view every time). My code so far:

```
spikes.loc[(stims.at[i, 'StimOnset'] <= spikes['SpikeTimes']) & (spikes['SpikeTimes'] <= stims.at[i, 'StimOffset']), 'StimPeriod'] = True
temp = spikes.loc[(stims.at[i, 'StimOnset'] <= spikes['SpikeTimes']) & (spikes['SpikeTimes'] <= stims.at[i, 'StimOffset'])]
temp['StimPeriod'] = True
```

(Sorry that it's so long, I don't see why it shouldn't work so I made sure ot include everything). So the first line performs the necessary computation, however the two following do not, and they also throw a warning. Now I could use the style of the first line for multiple computations, but that doesn't seem efficient. Is there any way around this so as to save the desired view in a variable?

A minimal code example to produce this effect:

```
d = {'A': [1,3,5,7], 'B': [2,4,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.loc[(3 <= df['A']) & (df['A'] <= 5), 'A'] = 0
print df
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
temp = df.loc[(3 <= df['A']) & (df['A'] <= 5)]
temp['A'] = 0
print df
```

the first part produces the desired effect, the second does not.
The warning goes as follows:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:8:
>   SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
>   slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] =
>   value instead
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
>   http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: what is the warning?
Also can you please provide a minimal example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by not taking a part of the original dataframe, but by getting a set of indices from it, for the mini example:

```
d = {'A': [1,3,5,7], 'B': [2,4,6,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
temp = (df.loc[:,'A'] >= 3) & (df.loc[:,'A'] <= 5)
df.loc[temp,'A'] = 0
print df
```

gives the desired result, I could imagine there are better solutions but it's not completely horrible anymore.